# Javascript split URL and select string to be placed in a table

Tags: javascript, url, google-chrome-extension, google-ad-manager

I'm working on a script for a Chrome extension and what it does is that it splits GPT Ad Request URL and strings are inserted into a table.

Here's an example of the request URL:

```
https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?gdfp_req=1&pvsid=933914290088983&correlator=2431396676467655&output=ldjh&impl=fifs&eid=21062833%2C21065233%2C21065310&vrg=2019121002&guci=2.2.0.0.2.2.0.0&sc=1&sfv=1-0-37&ecs=20200103&iu_parts=114240681%2Cipropertymy%2Crent%2Cpropertydetails&enc_prev_ius=0%2F1%2F2%2F3&prev_iu_szs=1x1&ists=1&prev_scp=location1%3Dselangor%26location2%3Dcyberjaya%26location3%3Dhyve%26propertytype%3Dserviced-residence%26bedroom%3DStudio%26size%3D500-1000%26rentprice%3D800-1K%26position%3Dinterstitial%26lang%3Den-GB&cust_params=district%3D%26...
```

I've been going through the script that was prepared by someone else and I'm wondering how can I select which string value that can be displayed in a table. The request URL can get really long with other targeting parameters that is included.

Here's the sample script,

```
var consoles = document.getElementById("customers"),
  headers = [],
  table_rows = 0;

chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener(function(e) {
  if (e.request.url.indexOf("securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads") >= 0) {
    var n = e.request.url.split("&");

    (table_rows += 1),
      n.forEach(function(e, n) {
        "https:" == e.split("=")[0]
          ? s("Protocol", e.split("=")[0])
          : "" == e.split("=")[0] ||
            s(e.split("=")[0], unescape(e.split("=")[1]));
      });
  }

  function s(e, n) {
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

    if (1 == headers.includes(e)) {
      headers.findIndex(function(n) {
        return n === e;
      }),
        s.rows.length != table_rows + 1 && s.insertRow();
      var r = table_rows;

      if (s.rows[r].cells.length != t)
        for (var l = 0; l == t; l++) s.rows[r - 1].insertCell().innerHTML = "-";

      (s.rows[r].insertCell().innerHTML = n),
        "prev_scp" == e &&
          (s.rows[r].lastElementChild.innerText = decodeURIComponent(
            decodeURI(n.replace(/&/g, "\n"))
          ));
    } else {
      headers.push(e),
        0 == s.rows.length && s.insertRow(),
        (s.rows[0].insertCell().innerHTML = e);
      var t = s.rows[0].cells.length;
      1 == s.rows.length && s.insertRow();
      r = table_rows;

      if (s.rows[0].cells.length != t)
        for (l = s.rows[0].cells.length; l <= t; l++)
          (s.rows[0].insertCell().innerHTML = n || "-"), (n = null);
      else
        (s.rows[r].insertCell().innerHTML = n),
          "url" == e &&
            (s.rows[r].lastElementChild.innerText = decodeURIComponent(
              decodeURI(n.replace(/&/g, "\n"))
            ));
    }
  }
}),
  document.getElementById("reload").addEventListener("click", function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
  });
```

The current script produces this kind of table,

```
pvsid = 123456 
jar = 2020-1-6-10
eid = 21065332,21062889
correlator = 123456  
output = 10  
iu_parts = abcd,12,xyz 
prev_scp = position: abovefold
cust_params = lang=en-GB
```

I want to be able to only display these selected parameters,

```
pvsid = 12345
correlator = 123456
prev_scp = position: abovefold
cust_params = lang=eng-GB
```

Any idea on which method I can use to select which parameters that I would like to display from a split URL and then place it in the table?

Comment: it would really help if you could provide a simple example of 'before' and 'after' - i.e. with this url I want it split like this

Comment: I left an example above in the post, I hope it's helpful?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the script you have used gets all the rows and columns dynamically from the Table. From your query, I understand that you want to fetch only specific columns from the db table. In that case, you can form a html yourself including specific columns(note that it is static in this case since you are defining the columns), and also iterate through the JSONArray from backend and get only specific matching rows from iterated JSONArray Length. Please let me know if you followed my advice else I can help you in reconstructing the Data grid for you.